# HTML element flicker using jQuery .remove() function

Tags: jquery, flicker

forgive me if this is a repeat, but I couldn't find this specific answer. We have a Joomla 2.5 and ClickCartPro 8 (CCP) installation that works together to create one e-commerce website. I have a Joomla slider module that is displaying on the CCP store homepage, but it also shows up on every other store page.

I'm using some PHP to determine whether or not it's the store splash page, that's fine, and then a little jQuery to remove the HTML node, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
  jQuery('#ais_163_wrapper, #ais_163').remove();
});
```

That also works fine, except when a page loads slowly the slider appears for a split second and then disappears, particularly if it's not already cached.

Does anyone know how to make it not appear at all, zero flicker? Any help would be greatly appreciated. This site is still in development, it's [here](http://www.feltingsupply.com/shop/index.php) if you want to view the store part.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could always have the HTML output that particular block initially hidden, remove the element(s) that need removing, and finally in the callback function show/fade-in the wrapper.

#### HTML

```
<div id="some_wrapper" style="display:none;">
    <!-- HTML in question -->
</div>
```

#### JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ais_163_wrapper, #ais_163').remove(function(){
      $('#some_wrapper').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, couzzi! Not sure why I didn't think of that, already using that same thing on another site. I'll try that.